# How to format date in Javascript in this format: 2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998

Tags: javascript, .net, date, format

I have a .NET application that returns the date in this format: 2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998.
I need a Javascript form to format to "December 29, 2021".

All the examples I've found so far use "new date " to exemplify, like this example here:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE'));
```

that creates a date in a different format from mine and then it works. In my case it doesn't work.

Comment: Here's a hint:  `const currentDate = new Date('2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998');`

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en',{month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'})` will get pretty close. Be careful with `new Date('2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998')`, it will be parsed as local or an invalid date, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

```
new Date().toDateString("de-DE").substring(3)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I have this format date: "2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998" different from "new date";

Comment: if you want convert to this format  use this new Date("2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998").toDateString().substring(3)

Comment: That returns a date like "30.12.2021" (probably).

Comment: That worked:

"new Date("2021-12-29T15:04:09.0129998").toDateString().substring(3)"

Thanks for the help!